# Pandas resample based on datetime column where there're duplicate datetimes then plot

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have two columns time (e.g. 2019-02-13T22:31:47.000000000) and amount (e.g. 15). The time column might have duplicates.

What's the best way to resample amount into daily/monthly/yearly then plot?

I tried:

```
df.resample('M', on='time').sum().plot(x='time', y='amount')
```

but it says:

```
raise KeyError(key) from err
if is_scalar(key) and isna(key) and not self.hasnans:
KeyError: 'time'
```

Already verified that time is datetime (without null values):

```
df['time'].isnull().any()
false
```

Amount is float as well.

Comment: according to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) you should do some aggregation with `resample`, eg.g `df.resample('M', on='time').mean().plot(...)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang good catch, that was a mistake on my end. I edited and seems the new error is about the time column

Comment: Does just `df.resample('M', on='time').sum()` work? Aka, is your problem actually the `resample`, or is it the `plot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) says

> The object must have a datetime-like index

So, try:

```
df.set_index('time').resample('M').sum().plot(x='time', y='amount')
```

Comment: You can't resample directly when the index has duplicate values

Comment: That doesn't sound right. Try this simple example: `series = pd.Series(range(2), index=pd.to_datetime(['1/1/2000', '1/1/2000']))
series.resample('M').sum()` It doesn't raise any error